# Implementation of cost function in linear regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am trying to implement the cost function on a simple training dataset and visualise the cost function in 3D.

The shape of my cost function is not as it is supposed to be.

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

def create_array(start, end, resolution):
    return np.linspace(start, end, int((end - start)/resolution + 1))

def f(x,a,b):
    x = np.array(x)
    return a*x+b # or Theta_1 * x + Theta_0

def get_J(x, y, a, b):
    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)
    # return 1/(2*len(y)) * sum(pow(f(x,a,b) - y, 2))
    # Simple implementation
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        sum+= (f(x[i],a,b) - y[i])**2
    return 1/(2*len(y))*sum
    
# Training set
x = np.array([0,1,2,3])
y = np.array([0,1,2,3])

Theta_0 = create_array(-20, 10, 0.5)
Theta_1 = create_array(-20, 10, 0.5)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(Theta_0, Theta_1)
X=X.flatten()
Y=Y.flatten()
J = [get_J(x, y, X[i], Y[i]) for i in range(0,len(X))]

# simple set to verify 3D plotting is doing as expetected - OK
# X = [10, 0, -10,-20, 10, 0, -10,-20, 10, 0,-10, -20, 10, 0, -10,-20]
# Y = [-20, -20, -20, -20, -10, -10, -10, -10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10]
# J = [50, 25, 26, 60, 24, 10, 11, 26, 10, 0, 2, 11, 52, 26, 27, 63]

# Create the graphing elements
xyz = {'x': X, 'y': Y, 'z': J}
# put the data into a pandas DataFrame (this is what my data looks like)
df = pd.DataFrame(xyz, index=range(len(xyz['x']))) 
# re-create the 2D-arrays
x1 = np.linspace(df['x'].min(), df['x'].max(), len(df['x'].unique()))
y1 = np.linspace(df['y'].min(), df['y'].max(), len(df['y'].unique()))
x2, y2 = np.meshgrid(x1, y1)
z2 = griddata((df['x'], df['y']), df['z'], (x2, y2), method='cubic')

fig = plt.figure(figsize =(14, 9))
ax = Axes3D(fig)
surf = ax.plot_surface(x2, y2, z2, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=plt.get_cmap('coolwarm'),linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
ax.set_xlabel('\u03B81', fontweight ='bold')  
ax.set_ylabel('\u03B80', fontweight ='bold')  
ax.set_zlabel('J (\u03B81, \u03B80)', fontweight ='bold') 
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.show()
```

The 3D plot has the following shape:
[image]

when it is supposed to have this shape:
[image]

Comment: Where does the reference image come from? What are the equations to build the reference image? Do they use the same data?

Comment: @maij The reference image is coming from a course teaching these principles. There is no indication which dataset is used and it is quite possibly that the dataset might be different, so one should not stick on the J values. The shape though is supposed to be the same. Unfortunately, I cannot find my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take paper and pencil and analytically derive the `J` you have implemented, you arrive at something like this:

```
a = theta_1: -20 ... 10
b = theta_0: -20 ... 10
J(a,b) ~ b^2 + (a+b-1)^2 + (2a+b-2)^2 + (3a+b-3)^2
```

This basically means that `a` and `b` are coupled like `a+b`. The `a+b` like terms are squared and a plot of `(a+b)^2` looks like this (made with gnuplot):

[image: coupled]

The reference plot has another form which looks more like `a` and `b` being independent, as in `a^2 + b^2`, lets plot this:
[image: independent]

So we should be able to reproduce the reference plot if `J` has the form

```
J(a, b) ~ a^2 + b^2 + (other terms except a*b)
```

The form of `J` is given by the training set `x` and `y`. I leave it to you to show analytically that the  values in `x` build the coupling between `a` and `b`. For `y`, I play with the values and arrive at:

```
x = np.array([-1, 1])
y = np.array([1, -4])
```

This is the simplest setting I can think of. There are many more possibilities.

*I'm not that deep into machine learning and the meaning of these values. My knowledge basically comes from [here](https://machinelearningmedium.com/2017/08/11/cost-function-of-linear-regression/). So if I'm wrong please let me know.*

Now I get the following image, and I think it is quite close to the reference one, at least the shape:

[image: final]

As a summary: I don't think there is a bug in your implementation. I think, you have plotted different data.

Comment: There is a small bug in my code when calling the cost function, but not in the cost calculation itself. The main problem was in the dataset, though, as you very well pointed out. When adding training data that are symmetrical to the center of the Cartesian, the shape is as expected! I will go ahead and accept the answer :) Thank you for the very detailed explanation